# Iterating through a list or tuple?

Tags: python, list, tuples

I've got some coordinates stored as a list. I'm iterating over the list and I want to write the coordinates in a KML file. So I *should* end up with something resembling the following:

```
<coordinates>-1.59277777778, 53.8271055556</coordinates>
<coordinates>-1.57945488999, 59.8149016457</coordinates>
<coordinates>-8.57262235411, 51.1289412359</coordinates>
```

The problem i've got is that my code results in the first item in the list being duplicated three times:

```
 <coordinates>-1.59277777778, 53.8271055556</coordinates>
 <coordinates>-1.59277777778, 53.8271055556</coordinates>
 <coordinates>-1.59277777778, 53.8271055556</coordinates>
```

I think I know why it's happening, because the script sees the .strip line and prints the first item in the list 3 times.

Here is my code:

```
oneLat = ['53.8041778', '59.8149016457', '51.1289412359']
oneLong = ['1.5192528', '1.57945488999', '8.57262235411']

with open("file",'w') as f:
            f.write('''<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<kml xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2" xmlns:gx="http://www.google.com/kml/ext/2.2" xmlns:kml="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2" xmlns:atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom">
<Document>
    <name>TracePlace</name>
    <open>1</open>
    <Style id="Photo">
        <IconStyle>
            <Icon>
                <href>../pics/icon.jpg</href>
            </Icon>
        </IconStyle>
        <LineStyle>
            <width>0.75</width>
        </LineStyle>
    </Style>
<Folder>''')    

coord_pairs = zip(map(float, oneLong), map(float, oneLat))
itemsInListOne = int(len(oneLat))

iterations = itemsInListOne

num = 0

while num < iterations:
    num = num + 1
    for coord in coord_pairs:
        print (str(coord).strip('()'))
        f.write("\t\t<coordinates>" + "-" + (str(coord).strip('()')) + "</coordinates>\n")
        break

f.write('''
</Folder>
        </Document>
        </kml>''')
f.close()
```

How can I get the correct 'mapped' coordinates to write to the KML file? By the 'correct' coordinates, I mean like my first example

Thanks

Comment: Looks like you left out some source code. You don't have any closing quotes for the first `f.write()`.

Comment: Just added the missing code. I've only got one f.close() in this part of the script. The iteration writes the same chunk of code 3 times, which is what I need it to do. Once it has done 3 iterations, I close the file. The problem is that it is writing the same item from the list. I need it to write the next item in the list. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with your `break` line. You break out of the `coordPair` loop after only the first iteration. Your `while` loop runs `len(coordPairs)==3` times so the 1st item is repeated 3 times.

Here is your code with some improvements (annotated):

```
oneLat = ['53.8041778', '59.8149016457', '51.1289412359']
oneLong = ['1.5192528', '1.57945488999', '8.57262235411']

# Do the negation here, instead of in the string formatting later
coordPairs = zip((-float(x) for x in oneLong), (float(x) for x in oneLat))

with open("file",'w') as f:
    f.write(xmlHeaderStuff) # I've left out your string literal for brevity    

    #I assume the purpose of the two loops, the while loop and for loop,
    #is for the purpose of repeating the group of 3 coord pairs each time?

    for i in range(len(coordPairs)):
        for coord in coordPairs:
            f.write("\t\t<coordinates>{}, {}</coordinates>\n".format(*coord))
            # break <-- this needs to go

    f.write(xmlFooterStuff)

# f.close() <-- this is unnecessary, since the `with` block takes care of
# file closing automatically
```

Answer (score 0):

Why would you over complicate things so much? You introduced some weird `num` iteration counter and not used it at all. I am not gonna debug your code as it feels too bloated, but give you something to work on.

You can simply iterate over the `zip` object like this:

```
oneLat = ['53.8041778', '59.8149016457', '51.1289412359']
oneLong = ['1.5192528', '1.57945488999', '8.57262235411']


coord_pairs = zip(oneLong, oneLat)
for coord in coord_pairs:
    print( "{}, {}".format(coord[0], coord[1]) )
```

Ouput seems fine:

```
1.5192528, 53.8041778
1.57945488999, 59.8149016457
8.57262235411, 51.1289412359
```

I think you should be able wrap it up back with writing to file.

EDIT: OK, I figured out what was wrong. This while iterated 3 times over `coord_pairs`, but the loop has `break` inside, so it stops at 1st element of `coord_pairs`. This is why the 1st pair is repeated 3 times. Sorry to be frank but the code looks like Coding Under Influence.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why you're converting your input strings to floats, just so you can turn them into strings again. Here's a one liner to get a list of those strings:

```
['<coordinates>-{}, {}</coordinates>'.format(*pair) for pair in zip(oneLong, oneLat)]
```

Breaking it down...

The zip() returns tuples of (long, lat) pairs.

The [ ] comprehension consumes the zip, creating an element for the left hand part.

The left hand part uses the format() function to fill in the template with your strings.

The *pair expands the the tuple that comes back from the `zip()` so each member of that tuple is seen as an individual argument. If you don't care for that style of comprehension, you could be more explicit:

```
['<coordinates>-{}, {}</coordinates>'.format(long, lat) for long, lat in zip(oneLong, oneLat)]
```

If you have a lot of these, you'd be better of to replace the [list comprehension] with parens, which will just make it an iterator, so you don't have to create an intermediate list. Then you could do something like:

```
lines = ('<coordinates>-{}, {}</coordinates>\n'.format(*pair) for pair in zip(longIter, latIter))
with open('yourFile', 'w') as file:
    for line in lines:
        file.write(line)
```

longIter and latIter can be lists, or other forms of iterables.